# Splitting String Every 'n' Letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, loops

Suppose the input is `inp = qmnopqmnnm` and you want to check if any of these list items is the same as a substring in `inp`:

```
['nopqm', 'opqmn', 'pqmno', 'qmnop', 'mnopq']
```

How would you check if this is true?

My approach was to split the original input every n letters where n = len of one of the list items (4).

```
out = [(inp[i:i+lengthS]) for i in range(0, len(inp), lengthS)]
```

But this would only return:

```
['qmnop', 'qmnnm']
```

This should return `True` since qmn**opqmn**nm is in the list.

instead, I'm trying to find **every 4 characters** rather than splitting every 4

Comment: Without actually having tried it: `any([inp in word for word in length5])`, possibly. Assuming `length5` is that longer list.

Comment: Better to use `any(...)` instead of `any([...])` without the square brackets, because a list comprehension will not short-circuit.

Comment: @kaya3: thanks! I was wondering about that. Anyway, I got the variables around the wrong way. That duplicate has the answer to this, but it's hidden enough to repeat here: `any(word in inp for word in length5)` returns `True` for your test, `False` if there is no such match.